# how can i load a FLVplayback from a specific time?

Tags: flash, load, actionscript-3, flvplayback, flash-cs5

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import fl.video.*;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

fk.autoPlay = false;

// Parametreleri yüklüyoruz.
var myLoaderInfo=new Object();

//Parametrelerin yuklendigine emin olmak için false yapıldı.bunun daha sonra true olması gerekiyor.
myLoaderInfo.myParamsLoaded = false;

// Event.complete i cagırmak için kullanılır.
myLoaderInfo.loaderComplete = loaderComplete;

//video yuklendiginde myLoaderInfo.loaderComplete i cagırır.
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, myLoaderInfo.loaderComplete);

// Degiskenler yüklendiginde fonksiyon cagrılır.
myLoaderInfo.useParams = useParams;

function loaderComplete(myEvent:Event)
{
    this.myParams = this.loaderInfo.parameters;
    this.myParamsLoaded = true;//Parametrelerin yuklendigine emin olduk.

    this.useParams();

    //Başlangıç zamanından 1 saniye sonrasına kadar video yuklendi.
    //fk.bufferTime = startTime+1;
    //Video oynatılıyor.
    fk.play(src);
}

//degiskenler tanımlandı.
var src:String;
var startTime:Number;
var stopTime:Number;

//Parametreleri aldık.
function useParams()
{
    var obj:Object = new Object();
    var j;
    for (j in this.myParams)
    {
        if (j == "url")
        {
            src = this.myParams[j];
        }
        else if (j=="bas")
        {
            startTime = int(this.myParams[j]);
        }
        else
        {
            stopTime = int(this.myParams[j]);
        }
    }
}

fk.addEventListener(VideoEvent.READY, bitti);
function bitti(eventObject:VideoEvent):void
{
    //Videonun başlangıcını başlangıç zamanına getirdik.
    fk.seekSeconds(startTime);
}

// Her karede kontrol edecegizki, durma zamanını geçirmeyelim
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
function myFunction(event:Event)
{
    if (fk.playheadTime > stopTime)
    {
        fk.pause();
    }
}
```

I have a video. First, it loads. Then it starts from the time that I want to. Also, it stops from the time I want to. But I want to load my video only from start time to stop time. How can I do this or which method can I use?
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

To start a video at a specific location, you're probably going to want to use the NetStream object:
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html
and .seek(seconds) to get to the starting keyframe closest to the number of seconds you pass.

As far as stopping it, you can always setup a timer to fire after so many seconds after playing to stop the video.

There's a good resource for NetStream here: http://plasticsturgeon.com/?p=6

Comment: thanks.but i want to load only between starttime and stoptime.And as you can see i write the code that stops my video in enter frame event so my video stops at stoptime then when i press the play button it doesn't resume.so i want to ask what's the most painless way to dynamically load only the part of video required?